# Is there a way to use Openpyxl and Seaborn together? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn, openpyxl

I have several small datasets within an excel worksheet. I would like to create small graphs beside each dataset.

Here is my worksheet:

[image]

**Data**

Here is the data which is contained in the same worksheet in different cells.

```
Country    Sales        Date
Africa     5000000      2/1/2021
Italy      10000000     3/1/2021
UK         2000000      3/3/2021
Australia  1000000      3/5/2021
        
        
        
        
        
        
Names   Sales       Date
Bill    5000000     2/1/2021
Jane    10000000    3/1/2021
Lea     2000000     3/3/2021
Tanya   1000000     3/5/2021
```

**Desired**

I wish to point to each dataset within the worksheet and create a visual graph using seaborn or plotly. Is this possible to do this within a single worksheet that contains two sets of datasets?
How would I point to the data?

[image]

**Doing:**

graph = sns.barplot(data = book2, x = 'Date', y = 'Sales', hue = 'Country')

[image]

How would I navigate to two separate sections of data within a single worksheet and create a chart beside each dataset using Seaborn?
Is this possible or would I need to incorporate Openpyxl with this? (I prefer the  functionality and aesthetic of Seaborn)
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While this should be possible to do this with Seaborn plots – you need to save them as images and then add them, but as long as you can live with the charts that Excel produces, it would probably be easiert to do this.

Comment: Ok is it possible to have the seaborn graphs run interactively on a dashboard?

Comment: I don't think so but that's a completely separate question. If you use Excel's charts, they will update automatically when the data changes.